# Clearing a character string variable set in BASH

Tags: bash, variables

In learning to use BASH, I somehow set !" such that it is interpreted as a character string in each instance BASH interprets !" .  For example:

2013-MP-MFY3Y:~ williamdwyer$ echo !"

echo "FRom faireſt creatures we deſire increaſe,"

FRom faireſt creatures we deſire increaſe,

2013-MP-MFY3Y:~ williamdwyer$ rm !"

rm "FRom faireſt creatures we deſire increaſe,"

Problems arise in that every string ending in !" now substitutes in "FRom faireſt creatures we deſire increaſe," -- another example:

2013-MP-MFY3Y:~ williamdwyer$ echo "Now!"

echo "Now"FRom faireſt creatures we deſire increaſe,"

> 

How may I clear this mapping out?

Thank you!

I've tried rm, unset, echo "" > "!"", echo "" > '!"' .  I obviously do not understand how !" is being interpreted.

Comment: `type '!'` will tell you what it is.  unset should have worked if it's a variable so maybe it's a function?  `unset -f '!'` should do then.

Comment: It's safest to put exclamation marks in single-quotes to avoid triggering history expansion. You can also escape them, but the rules for that are a little weird. Double-quotes don't work on them at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bash's [Using History Interactively](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Using-History-Interactively). The `!` character starts a [History Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction)

`!"` is recalling the last command you entered that *starts with* `"`

A demo:

```bash
$ "foo bar"
bash: foo bar: command not found

$ echo !"
echo "foo bar"
foo bar
```

Comment: Thank you Glenn, Gordon, and Allan!  This does regard history expansion.  The stock BASH install on MacOS still uses 3.2 due to licensing issues.  More recent BASH versions allow for an exclamation mark (!) prior to a double quote (") without invoking history expansion, recalling the last command starting with (").